# Problems getting be_routable to work with rspec-rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a controller that I want to not have some routes, but I'm getting a weird error not being able to `respond to 'routable?`.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :patients do
  resources :encounters, except: :index
end

# encounters_controller.rb
def index
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  @encounters = @patient.encounters.all
end

# encounters_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe EncountersController do
  let(:valid_attributes) { Fabricate.attributes_for :encounter }
  let!(:encounter)       { Fabricate :encounter }
  before :example do
    @patient = encounter.patient
    @patient_appointment = { patient_id: @patient, id: encounter }
  end

  it 'route' do
    expect(get: '/encounters').not_to be_routeable
  end

end


$ rspec spec/controllers/encounters_controller_spec.rb --backtrace

EncountersController
  route (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) EncountersController route
     Failure/Error: expect(get: '/encounters').not_to be_routeable
       expected {:get=>"/encounters"} to respond to `routeable?`
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:37:in `handle_failure'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:70:in `handle_matcher'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:67:in `not_to'
     # ./spec/controllers/encounters_controller_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:151:in `instance_exec'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:151:in `block in run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:380:in `execute_with'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:321:in `instance_exec'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:380:in `execute_with'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:221:in `call'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:447:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:500:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:330:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:500:in `block in run_examples'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `map'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `run_examples'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:463:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `map'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:53:in `report'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
     # ./vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.1.5/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # ./vendor/bundle/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # ./vendor/bundle/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.19688 seconds (files took 1.04 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

When trying with a new test app and scaffolded code,  `be_routable` works fine. I really don't understand why. Regardless what I put inside the `expect`, I always stumble in responding to `routeable?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo... should be:

```
expect(get: '/encounters').not_to be_routable
```

(be_routable, not be_routeable)

I did the same thing as well when I first tried it :)

Comment: OMG, you are right.... I can't believe I have spent so many hours with this issue. Marking your answer as solved is not enough to show my gratitude, so if by chance you come to Chile, I'll invite you a beer (or a coffee).

Comment: Sounds good my friend, don't worry, I did the exact same thing :) Glad I could help!